# Devise Signout Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I'm using Devise 1.5.1 in a Rails 3.0.3 app.  It works well, with one exception: The signout link gives me this error:

> **Routing Error**
>
> > uninitialized constant UsersController

The link that leads to this is:

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

I haven't created an app/controllers/user_controller.rb file, but my understanding that this wasn't necessary when using Devise, correct?

In case it's relevant, my routes.rb file looks like:

```
Su::Application.routes.draw do

 get "group/create"

  devise_for :users

  resources :users
  resources :payers
  resources :payments
  resources :categories
  resources :groups

  match "adduser", :to => "groups#adduser"

  root :to => "pages#home"
end
```

...and app/models/user.rb looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :group_id
end
```

I have googled and searched on SO extensively, but to no avail.  How should I troubleshoot something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your routes file, you have

> devise_for :users

which serves for the routes for Devise, but

> resources :users

is a generic CRUD route, which makes Rails to think that in your app, you have `Users Controller`, and that you are doing something with the Users model in your model.

The error tells that you don't have a Users Controller and that's true, but it's looking for it because of the route.
So, either delete the line or add a Users Controller if you want to do something with the Users model.

If anything is not clear, post it as a comment.