# rails Devise showing uninitialized constant while logging out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i have an app which uses devise and i have created the login for company 
this is my routes file

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :companies
  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :companies do
    resource :company_profile do
      member do
        post :follow_company
        post :unfollow_company
      end
    end
    resources :events do
      member do
        post :follow_event
        post :unfollow_event

      end
      collection do
        get :new_job
      end
      get :job_pending
    end
    resources :company_profiles do
      collection do
        get :job_status
      end
    end
  end
end
```

i have a profiles controller for the company , 
i am facing the issue when i try to signout it gives me error when i click on this link `<%= link_to "log out", destroy_company_session_path, method:  :delete, :class => 'button' %>`

**uninitialized constant CompaniesController**

this issue is arising when i try to signout when i dont have company id in the url

like when i am on the page where the url is

```
localhost:3000/companies/1/company_profile
```

it logs me out properly , but when  i try to signout from localhost:3000

it gives me the error , dont know whats going on

Comment: What is `destroy_individual_session_path`? Is that pseudocode? Or have you left something out of your routes? At quick glance I don't see it in the routes produced by devise.

Comment: @MichaelCruz - updated the code , because i had two types of login thats why written by mistake, but behaviour is same in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so hard i finally found the solution , i needed to change the sign out method from delete to get but i don't know why i need to do a GET method for signing out

for `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get`

Comment: It's because you aren't actually deleting any data from the database. You are merely deleting a session, which is stored in a cookie.

Comment: but why it was searching for the companies controller though it was the devise route

Comment: Probably should have asked this to begin with, but do you have a companies_controller.rb with `class CompaniesController` defined within in your controllers?

Comment: no i dont have it , as i am using devise i didnt create

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of your error. As for why it works as a GET method, I'm not sure - that's strange. But you could look into the devise documentation further to search out an answer about that.

Answer (score 2):

By adding `resources :companies`, you are telling Rails that there is a CompaniesController, but you aren't defining one. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276027/devise-signout-routing-error) for more details, but essentially if you are going to have `devise_for :companies` AND `resources :companies`, you need to define a CompaniesController.